# Connection Pooling Statistics with Redisson

Tags: spring-boot, redis, micrometer, redisson

I am using Redisson as a Redis Client for my spring boot application. 
I want to have my connection pooling statistics/metrics and publish it to micrometer.

Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: did you find anything?
I also need to get my redis connection pool statistics in my application